# 08 Hyundai Santa Fe Evap Leak (Large)

Tags: hyundai, evap, santa-fe

My 08 Hyundai Santa Fe, 86k miles, check engine light came on, then I smelled fuel.  I had it scanned and it said Evap Leak Large, fuel level sensors.  Can this be correct?  Should it be the fuel pressure sensor?

Mike

Answer (score 1):

The EVAP system prevents excess vacuum and vapor buildup in a sealed fuel tank system. A big difference is the ability of the enhanced system to monitor it's operation. The vehicle will run a vacuum or a pressure test depending on the model and inform the PCM of any leak greater than 0.020 in. (0.5 mm). Certain criteria (the drive cycle) must be met for the test to run and the large leak test is always run before the small leak test.

A **P0457 gross** leak detected code is often the result of the vehicle operators not tightening the refueling cap correctly after refueling. The same is true for the P0455 large leak code. Please note that a loose gas cap is not the only possible cause, but it is certainly the most likely. It could also be a cracked or loose hose, faulty gas tank seams, or anything else that may cause a large leak in the sealed EVAP system. A thorough visual inspection will often reveal loose hoses and lines.

The PCM will run a **large leak test** when it receives a signal from the fuel level sensor indicating an increase in fuel level (after refueling). If the fuel filler cap were left loose or worse off the fill tube, the PCM would set a pending code and illuminate the MIL in an attempt to warn the driver of the situation.

**Here are some Powetrain Control Module diagnostic codes**

P0441: Incorrect purge flow (PURGE VALVE LEAK)

P0442: Small leak

P0443: Purge solenoid electrical fault

P0446: Blocked canister vent (HIGH SYSTEM VACUUM)

P0449: Canister vent solenoid electrical fault

P0452: Tank pressure sensor voltage (LOW)

P0453: Tank pressure sensor voltage (HIGH)

P0454: Tank pressure sensor voltage (NOISY)

P0455: LARGE LEAK (LOW SYSTEM VACUUM)

P0456: Very small leak

P0457: GROSS LEAK (CAP OFF)

P0460: Fuel level circuit

P0461: Fuel level sensor (STUCK/NOISY)

P0462: Fuel level sensor (VOLTAGE LOW)

P0463: Fuel level sensor (VOLTAGE HIGH)

P0464: Fuel level sensor (VOLTAGE NOISY AT IDLE)

**Hope it helps!**